# SSL proxy error with tfsonline and TeamCity

Tags: tfs, teamcity, azure-devops

When I set up my project in TeamCity to connect to a version control system root on *tfsonline*. However, I keep getting a problem related to ServicePointManager claiming some proxy doesn't support HTTPS.

How can I fix this problem? Is there's some additional configuration needed to get it to work?

The error I get:

```
Server='https://XXXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/XXXX'
Username='fredrik@XXXXX'
ERROR - The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme.
System.Exception: The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by installing Visual Studio 2012, updates on the server, and all available updates in [Windows Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Update).